# How to install new Skype in Ubuntu 17.10 and later

Tags: skype, 17.10

Microsoft just release the new Skype client.
I downloaded it from https://www.skype.com/en/get-skype/

The compressed folder has a usr folder with a lot of other files in it. How do I install it ?

sindre@selite:~/Install$ tree usr

```
usr
├── bin
│   └── skypeforlinux
└── share
    ├── applications
    │   └── skypeforlinux.desktop
    ├── doc
    │   └── skypeforlinux
    │       └── third-party_attributions.html
    ├── icons
    │   └── hicolor
    │       ├── 1024x1024
    │       │   └── apps
    │       │       └── skypeforlinux.png
    │       ├── 16x16
    │       │   └── apps
    │       │       └── skypeforlinux.png
    │       ├── 256x256
    │       │   └── apps
    │       │       └── skypeforlinux.png
    │       ├── 32x32
    │       │   └── apps
    │       │       └── skypeforlinux.png
    │       └── 512x512
    │           └── apps
    │               └── skypeforlinux.png
    ├── pixmaps
    │   └── skypeforlinux.png
    └── skypeforlinux
        ├── blink_image_resources_200_percent.pak
        ├── content_resources_200_percent.pak
        ├── content_shell.pak
        ├── icudtl.dat
        ├── libffmpeg.so
        ├── libnode.so
        ├── LICENSES.chromium.html
        ├── locales
        │   ├── am.pak
        │   ├── ar.pak
        │   ├── bg.pak
        │   ├── bn.pak
        │   ├── ca.pak
        │   ├── cs.pak
        │   ├── da.pak
        │   ├── de.pak
        │   ├── el.pak
        │   ├── en-GB.pak
        │   ├── en-US.pak
        │   ├── es-419.pak
        │   ├── es.pak
        │   ├── et.pak
        │   ├── fake-bidi.pak
        │   ├── fa.pak
        │   ├── fil.pak
        │   ├── fi.pak
        │   ├── fr.pak
        │   ├── gu.pak
        │   ├── he.pak
        │   ├── hi.pak
        │   ├── hr.pak
        │   ├── hu.pak
        │   ├── id.pak
        │   ├── it.pak
        │   ├── ja.pak
        │   ├── kn.pak
        │   ├── ko.pak
        │   ├── lt.pak
        │   ├── lv.pak
        │   ├── ml.pak
        │   ├── mr.pak
        │   ├── ms.pak
        │   ├── nb.pak
        │   ├── nl.pak
        │   ├── pl.pak
        │   ├── pt-BR.pak
        │   ├── pt-PT.pak
        │   ├── ro.pak
        │   ├── ru.pak
        │   ├── sk.pak
        │   ├── sl.pak
        │   ├── sr.pak
        │   ├── sv.pak
        │   ├── sw.pak
        │   ├── ta.pak
        │   ├── te.pak
        │   ├── th.pak
        │   ├── tr.pak
        │   ├── uk.pak
        │   ├── vi.pak
        │   ├── zh-CN.pak
        │   └── zh-TW.pak
        ├── natives_blob.bin
        ├── pdf_viewer_resources.pak
        ├── resources
        │   ├── app.asar
        │   ├── app.asar.unpacked
        │   │   └── node_modules
        │   │       ├── keyboard-layout
        │   │       │   └── build
        │   │       │       └── Release
        │   │       │           └── keyboard-layout-manager.node
        │   │       ├── keytar
        │   │       │   └── build
        │   │       │       └── Release
        │   │       │           └── keytar.node
        │   │       ├── @paulcbetts
        │   │       │   ├── cld
        │   │       │   │   └── build
        │   │       │   │       └── Release
        │   │       │   │           └── cld.node
        │   │       │   └── spellchecker
        │   │       │       └── build
        │   │       │           └── Release
        │   │       │               └── spellchecker.node
        │   │       ├── slimcore
        │   │       │   └── bin
        │   │       │       ├── sharing-indicator.node
        │   │       │       └── slimcore.node
        │   │       └── sqlite3
        │   │           └── lib
        │   │               └── binding
        │   │                   └── node_sqlite3.node
        │   ├── default_app.asar
        │   └── electron.asar
        ├── skypeforlinux
        ├── snapshot_blob.bin
        ├── ui_resources_200_percent.pak
        ├── version
        └── views_resources_200_percent.pak

41 directories, 87 files
```

(Question is for new Skype for Ubuntu 17.10. Old answers does not help.)

Comment: On Ubuntu, you would download the file `skypeforlinux-64.deb` and install that with `sudo dpkg -i skypeforlinux-64.deb`. Of just double-click the file in the Downloads folder.

Comment: You need to make sure that you're downloading the .deb files [Debian / Ubuntu] rather than the .rpm [Red Hat].
It "should" download something, 63megs of .deb file. Click / double clicking "should" open the Ubuntu Software, after which yo should be able to "auto" install.

Comment: Have you tried double clicking the .deb file?

Comment: I do not think this is a duplicate, since the main answers of the other question are no longer valid. Skype has changed his client since the summer 2017

Comment: To be more precise: Skype rejects connections from the old client since the summer 2017. So the pominent answers in the “duplicate” question are no longer useful, even on old versions of Ubuntu

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Updated 1-2-2018**

Canonical has announced that Skype is now available as a Snap, so it can be installed direct from the Ubuntu-Software or by using snap:

```
snap install --classic skype
```

or you can use the link: [https://snapcraft.io/skype](https://snapcraft.io/skype/?_ga=2.111298052.1663943272.1517510263-600341392.1508576088)

**Old Method**

If you prefer to install it with Debian package manager use the old method:

Refer to the  https://www.skype.com/en/get-skype/ page. Then choose the option

> get Skype for linux Deb

then a `.deb` file will be downloaded. Open the terminal, refer to the folder where the `.deb` was downloaded (Or right mouse click in the folder and choose open in terminal). Then run:

`sudo dpkg -i skypeforlinux-64.deb`

if it showes any problem run: `sudo apt install -f`

when it finishes delete the `skypeforlinux-64.deb` file.

Comment: This site has a way to add the last (2017) client of  Skype so that it is upgraded when you perform an apt upgrade:  https://websiteforstudents.com/install-upgrade-skype-ubuntu-17-04-17-10/

Comment: @FrédéricGrosshans This worked very smoothely.

Comment: That `websiteforstudents.com` looks nice, but when I click on it, it hijacks Firefox to try to force me to do a "manual update". Nasty. The Skype instructions are good, though, so I've saved the page [in a gist](https://gist.github.com/dajare/e25bb93a56b4d022ff74f19737df5a6d) if anyone wants to save the aggro from the original site (also linked in the gist).